# toilet making noise

Tags: plumbing, toilet

my toilet has been making a noise the past couple of days.  I noticed a black tube at the bottom of the well. So I googled it and tried putting where it seems to go, but that doesn't work. Any help plz?

[image]

Comment: What kind of noise? A banging? A rattling? A whistle or whining sound?

Comment: a ripple in the water in the toilet

Answer (score 1):

It may be time to replace the flapper  that controls the flushing water. It is a quick, easy and inexpensive fix. Replacements can be bought at home Depot, Lowes, or any hardware or plumbing store. Or the fill valve may need to be replaced. Pull the black rubber tube from the overflow pipe to see if any water is running out of it when the fill valve shuts off indicating that the valve does not fully shut off the water supply.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the flapper is definitely a good idea.  The flapper costs around $5-$6 at big box stores.  I suggest to replace the flush valve too at the same time.  You can save money by getting a package deal which has both the flush valve and the flapper.